# ОКРАШИВАНИЕ ЯЧЕЙКИ

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Собственно в ячейке может быть два значения, при одном из них надо что бы эта ячейка окрашивалась (в любой цвет). Есть такой скрипт?
Мой который ниже не работает.

```
function color() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('B2:B').activate('Сюжет (со звуком)');
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#4a86e8');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let column = e.range.getColumn();
  let value = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column).getValue();

  if (value == "Сюжет (со звуком)") {
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setBackground('#4a86e8');
  }

}
```

Но лучше использовать условное форматирование!